Words for interaction dynamics, specific
How would you construct a word to describe the following scenario:

a person talks to you, in one to one correspondence, between a word (or set of words) said, and a face portrayed

the face, changes, in a step function manner (each face is distinct, and each, face, is distinct, in corresponding to something said

each face, is an engram (it is a picture that takes you back to a past experience

you, interact, as per the past experience


I want a word for this. The word must describe that the dialogue is taken from the broken up process, described, above.
Then, you go somewhere
The entire thing said remains
I want a word for this.
(the, dialogue, ... between, the two people, remains, a bit as being said by the puppet you will next look at, and, a bit, remaining as what you said in the puppet's, thought, cloud).
If, you are, relaxing,
you may portray the dialogue onto the face of a toy you are looking at.
This may result from situations, such as , voidness, fear, or time, passing (even, with medication, lengthening your concentration and inability to act or perceive), and the desire or push, from the empty, to do, something.
I want a name for this.
That is three words, that do not exist, in current languages. Any suggestions would be appropriate.

The past experiences may be with other people. The face, resembles, them.

I am thinking of how to structure this and similar interaction dynamics with vocabulary.

The first word, I suggest, is a "stont".

The second word, is a "strabil".

The third, is a "flaxseen".

But that wouldn't be a very good choice, because it, in, my, mind, derives, from a very, specific... experience, with flax seeds (someone showing them to me, and me saying, it's, not that

It is inappropriate, you may like the flax seeds, but, really... we are taking about something else

Let's call it, "embsimportrayal"

Perhaps I should delete my post.

I'm not sure this question can be answered exactly. As far as I know, no natural language has words this precise, so you have two choices: Either create your own derivational morphology that could produce things like these, or just... make up words that you think sound fitting.
But in fact, your comments suggest you've already done the latter, so now the question is, what do you require help with?
